# Failed to speed up the execution process of a script using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to implement `concurrent.futures` or something similar within the following script to make the execution faster. However, When I compare the two scripts, I see no change in speed. What possible change should I bring about to achieve the same?

Original script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = 'https://ldc.lloyds.com/market-directory/results'

params = {
    'cobc': '','cob': '','loc': '','ltti': '',
    'bro': '0','cov': '1','man': '0','mem': '0',
    'omc': '0','run': '0','name': '','mode':' cov',
    'c_page': 1 #---------------->unknown number of pages to traverse
}

def get_content(s,link,params):
    while True:
        r = s.get(link,params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        if not soup.select(".marketing-directories-results .contact-details > h2"): 
            return

        for item in soup.select(".marketing-directories-results .contact-details > h2"):
            yield item.text

        params['c_page']+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_content(s,link,params):
            print(item)
```

When I implement `concurrent.futures` within the script, I don't see any speed related improvement in the execution process:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import concurrent.futures as futures

link = 'https://ldc.lloyds.com/market-directory/results'

params = {
    'cobc': '','cob': '','loc': '','ltti': '',
    'bro': '0','cov': '1','man': '0','mem': '0',
    'omc': '0','run': '0','name': '','mode':' cov',
    'c_page': 1  #---------------->unknown number of pages to traverse
}

def get_content(s,link,params):

    while True:
        item_list = []
        r = s.get(link,params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        if not soup.select(".marketing-directories-results .contact-details > h2"): 
            return

        for item in soup.select(".marketing-directories-results .contact-details > h2"):
            print(item.text)

        params['c_page']+=1
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'

        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            future_to_url = {executor.submit(get_content, s, url, params): url for url in [link]}
            futures.as_completed(future_to_url)
```

> How can I implement `concurrent.futures` or something similar to speed the execution up?

Comment: You are instantiating a single thread. That won't help in this case. In fact it's likely to be marginally slower (due to thread pool construction etc) than running the function synchronously. If you had multiple URLs to gather data from then multi-threading would be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're passing `link` url variable as list in argument of `executor.submit` function. And it will be treated like `['h','t','t','p',.. so on]`.

I would suggest implementing like this:

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
from functools import partial

thread_func = partial(get_content,s, url)
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_worker=5) as pool:
    result = pool.map(thread_func, params)
```

I have used partial function just to be clear on what's being passed as iterator argument in map function.

Hope you'll find this helpful.